# Issue with default audio player in Chromium based browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website but I am having issues with the audio player in Chromium based browsers. The audio files play correctly in all browsers but the controls only show up in Firefox. In Chrome or Edge there are no controls, it is only blank space. If I switch the tags to `<video>` then Chromium browsers have controls, but I can't get it to work with the `<audio>` tag.

Here are screenshots of what I mean

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLqC3.jpg)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcx7V.jpg)

Does anyone know what is happening? Here is my HTML for this section of the site

```
<body>
    <script>
        var dailyAgent = "{{ daily_agent }}";
        var dailyAgentImageFilename = "{{ daily_agent_image_filename }}"; // Add this line
        var selectedFiles = JSON.parse('{{ selected_files | tojson | safe }}');
        var maps = JSON.parse('{{ maps | tojson | safe }}');
    </script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>      

    <!-- Start of site content-->
    <h1>STEPDLE</h1> 

    <button id="howToPlayBtn" class="how-to-play-button">How to Play</button> 

    <div id="gameArea">
        <div id="mediaContainer">
            <img id="gameImage" src="" alt="Map">
            <audio controls id="agentSound">
                <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>            
        </div>
        
        <div id="agentGrid">
            {% for agent_name, agent_data in agents.items() %}
                <div class="agent-container">
                    <img class="agent" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='agents/' + agent_name + '/' + agent_data['icon']) }}" alt="{{ agent_name }}">
                    <div class="agent-marked"></div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>               
    </div>
```

This is a dynamic website built with Flask, where my app.py script sends a
render_template containing the filenames it wants the site to load. This is my CSS for this portion of the site

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: var(--primary-blue);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'VALORANT Font', sans-serif;
    font-size: 7em;
    color: var(--primary-red);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#gameArea {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 72% 28%;
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#mediaContainer {
    border: 10px solid var(--primary-red);
    background-color: var(--primary-blue);
    padding: 0px;
}

#mediaContainer img,
#mediaContainer audio {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#agentSound {
    filter: hue-rotate(165deg) brightness(0.9);
    min-width: 280px;
}

#agentGrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    background-color: var(--primary-blue);
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 6px solid var(--primary-red);
}
```

Also I will include the JS that is loading the audio

```
// Function to play the sound file for the current guess
    const playSound = (guessNumber) => {
        if (guessNumber < 5) {
            const soundFileName = selectedFiles[guessNumber];
            const mapName = maps[guessNumber];
            if (soundFileName && mapName) {
                const soundPath = `static/agents/${dailyAgent}/${soundFileName}`;
                const imagePath = `static/maps/${mapName}.png`;
                //console.log("Playing sound:", soundPath);
                agentSound.src = soundPath;
                document.getElementById('gameImage').src = imagePath; // Update map image
                if(guessNumber > 0){
                    agentSound.play().catch(e => console.error("Error playing sound:", e));
                }
            } else {
                console.error("Sound file or map not found for guess number", guessNumber);
            }
        }
    };
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on? You can actually test this site for yourself, it is live https://stepdle.fun

I have tried setting a defined width, changing  to  and tried a bunch of CSS tags

Comment: The controls are appearing just fine for me in Chrome https://i.imgur.com/YzETFz4.png. Check you've not got an extension installed or something else in your browser which is interfering with the audio controls.

Comment: I was able to find the issue, it was with this CSS

#mediaContainer img,
#mediaContainer audio {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

The height:auto; line was causing the player controls to disappear in Chrome.